# How to get desired output for the given "G-Man" problem

Tags: go, error-handling, file-io, logic, file-handling

Context:

G-Man is a video game in which G-Man has to move from one point to another on a grid (6 X 6 grid). There could be multiple paths between a source coordinate and destination coordinate and G-Man needs to reach the destination by spending least amount of power.

Position:

```
 G-Man’s position is located by the x, y coordinate of the grid. 
 One of the four compass points N, E, S and W indicates the direction G-Man is facing. 
 Eg: 2, 1 N means the G-Man is at 2 on the x coordinate, 1 on the y coordinate, and facing North.
```

6 X 6 Grid Moves

At the start of the game, G-Man is given a power of 200 units. His power is reduced for every move and turn he takes.

```
G-Man can turn left or right 90 degrees at a time to change his direction.
For every turn G-Man makes, his power is reduced by 5.
For every move that G-Man makes by 1 grid point, his power is reduced by 10.
      eg: If G-Man moves from 2, 1 E to the destination 4, 1 he loses 20 power points. 
      eg: If G-Man moves from 2, 1 S to 4, 5; he has to turn twice and move 6 grid points. So he loses 70 power points.
```

Goal

Given the source and destination coordinates, G-Man needs to reach the destination by spending least amount of power. And you need to print the remaining power he has after taking the shortest path with minimum number of turns.

Assumptions

```
 The grid is 6 X 6. All coordinates will have values between 0 - 6. 
 Direction value can either be N, E, W or S. 
 There could be multiple paths from source to destination. 
 G-Man will spend the least amount of power to reach the destination. 
 All the destination paths will be on the grid. 
 Only the final coordinates of the destination need to be considered. There is no need to consider the direction of the destination.
```

INPUT:
SOURCE 2 1 E
DESTINATION4 3

OUTPUT:
POWER 155

BUT I AM GETTING OUTPUT AS 90

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var Source []string
var Destination []string

const (
    gridSize  = 6
    maxPower  = 200
    movePower = 10
    turnPower = 5
)

func main() {
    cliArgs := os.Args[1:]

    if len(cliArgs) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Please provide the input file path")

        return
    }

    filePath := cliArgs[0]
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening the input file")

        return
    }

    defer file.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    for scanner.Scan() {

        args := scanner.Text()
        argList := strings.Fields(args)

        designation := argList[0]
        coordinates := argList[1:]

        if designation == "SOURCE" {
            Source = coordinates
        }
        if designation == "DESTINATION" {
            Destination = coordinates
        }
    }

    RemainingPower := solveForShortestPath(Source, Destination)
    fmt.Printf("POWER %d", RemainingPower)
}
```

PriorityQueue.go

```
package main

type Cell struct {
    X, Y      int
    Power     int
    Direction string
}

type PriorityQueue []*Cell

func (pq PriorityQueue) Len() int {
    return len(pq)
}

func (pq PriorityQueue) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return pq[i].Power < pq[j].Power
}

func (pq PriorityQueue) Swap(i, j int) {
    pq[i], pq[j] = pq[j], pq[i]
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
    item := x.(*Cell)
    *pq = append(*pq, item)
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Pop() interface{} {
    old := *pq
    n := len(old)
    item := old[n-1]
    *pq = old[0 : n-1]
    return item
}
```

solveForShortestPath.go

```
package main

import (
    "container/heap"
    "strconv"
)

func solveForShortestPath(Source, Destination []string) int {
    sourceX, _ := strconv.Atoi(Source[0])
    sourceY, _ := strconv.Atoi(Source[1])

    destX, _ := strconv.Atoi(Destination[0])
    destY, _ := strconv.Atoi(Destination[1])

    visited := make([][]bool, gridSize)
    for i := range visited {
        visited[i] = make([]bool, gridSize)
    }

    pq := make(PriorityQueue, 0)
    heap.Init(&pq)

    sourceCell := &Cell{X: sourceX, Y: sourceY, Power: maxPower, Direction: Source[2]}
    heap.Push(&pq, sourceCell)
    visited[sourceX][sourceY] = true

    for len(pq) > 0 {
        currentCell := heap.Pop(&pq).(*Cell)

        row := currentCell.X
        col := currentCell.Y
        dir := currentCell.Direction

        if row == destX && col == destY {
            return currentCell.Power
        }

        delRow := []int{-1, 0, +1, 0}
        delCol := []int{0, +1, 0, -1}
        for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
            newRow := row + delRow[i]
            newCol := col + delCol[i]

            if newRow >= 0 && newRow < gridSize && newCol >= 0 && newCol < gridSize && !visited[newRow][newCol] {
                newPower := currentCell.Power
                newDirection := getNewDirection(dir, delRow[i], delCol[i])
                if newDirection != dir {
                    newPower -= turnPower
                }
                newPower -= movePower
                if newPower >= 0 {
                    visited[newRow][newCol] = true
                    heap.Push(&pq, &Cell{X: newRow, Y: newCol, Power: newPower, Direction: dir})
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

getNewDirection.go

```
package main

func getNewDirection(currentDirection string, delRow int, delCol int) string {
    if currentDirection == "E" && delRow == 0 {
        return "E"
    } else if currentDirection == "E" && delRow == -1 {
        return "N"
    } else if currentDirection == "E" && delRow == +1 {
        return "S"
    } else if currentDirection == "S" && delCol == 0 {
        return "S"
    } else if currentDirection == "S" && delCol == -1 {
        return "W"
    } else if currentDirection == "S" && delCol == 1 {
        return "E"
    } else if currentDirection == "W" && delRow == -1 {
        return "N"
    } else if currentDirection == "W" && delRow == 0 {
        return "W"
    } else if currentDirection == "W" && delRow == 1 {
        return "S"
    } else if currentDirection == "N" && delCol == 0 {
        return "N"
    } else if currentDirection == "N" && delCol == 1 {
        return "E"
    }
    return "W"
}
```

Comment: I think you need to know the initial direction that G-Man is facing. Working back from the answer, you have one turn and 4 steps, which implies that the initial direction is correct for some of these 4 steps. If you think about it, you only need to turn at most twice no matter what direction G-Man initially faces.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static int calculatePower(int sX, int sY, int dX, int dY, String dir) {
    int deltaX = Math.abs(dX - sX);
    int deltaY = Math.abs(dY - sY);

    int turns = 0;
    
    if((dY < sY) && !dir.equals("S")) {
        turns++;
    } else if((dY > sY) && !dir.equals("N")) {
        turns++;
    }
    if((dX < sX) && !dir.equals("W")) {
        turns++;
    } else if((dX > sX) && !dir.equals("E")) {
        turns++;
    }

    int powerUsedForTurns = turns * 5;
    int powerUsedForMoves = (deltaX + deltaY) * 10;

    return 200 - (powerUsedForTurns + powerUsedForMoves);
}
```

Try this code